# Making line() clickable and redirectable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel's Notification library to send mails, I can send mails without a problem.

My main goal is, the mail function sends mail about whose birthday in the database. When I send mail, it only displays name of whose that is their birthday.

But the names should be clickable, and it should redirect them to information page about them, in this case `URL/students/ID`

I've tried addind `url()` to it, but it is a `line()` not an `action()`, because of that it didnt work. I've also tried adding `<a href="URL"></a>` to it, but it didn't work aswell.

I'm using one to many relation to retrieve the records, and use `where` queries to get their birthday.

**That is my *toMail()* function**

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->from('admin@site.com')
                    ->line('Hello, '.auth()->user()->name.'!')
                    ->line('Today is birthday of:')
                    ->line($user->students()
                        ->whereDay('birth_date', Carbon::now()->day)
                        ->whereMonth('birth_date', Carbon::now()->month)
                        ->pluck('first_name')->implode('<br/>'));
    }
```

That displays the records that their birthday is today without a problem. My goal is to make their names clickable, and it should redirect them to page with their ID. Like `students.com/students/5`

**email.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
<a href="{{url("/students/$line")}}">{!! $line !!}</a>

@endforeach
```

Please  help me, thanks!

Comment: Side note, `User::find(auth()->user()->id)` is totally redundant... `auth()->user()` returns the same thing as `User::find(auth()->user()->id)`; you're doubling your queries for no reason :) Just do `$user = auth()->user();` Also, `->line('Hello, '.auth()->user()->name.'!')` can simply be `->line("Hello, {$user->name}!")`

Comment: Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd like to write my mail templates manually but if you prefer this way use an instance of the [`HtmlString`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/HtmlString.html) class to display custom, unescaped HTML within a line:

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->line(new HtmlString('<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>'))
```

An example on how to specifically implement your case:

```
$students = $user->students()
    ->whereDay('birth_date', Carbon::now()->day)
    ->whereMonth('birth_date', Carbon::now()->month)
    ->get();

return (new MailMessage)
    ->from('admin@site.com')
    ->line('Hello, '.auth()->user()->name.'!')
    ->line('Today is birthday of:')
    ->line(new HtmlString(
        $students
            ->map(fn ($student, $index) => '<a href="/students/'.$student->id.'">'.$student->first_name.'</a>')
            ->implode('')
    ));
```

Comment: I retrieve the data (name) with `pluck()`. How can I implement that to my code? I've seen `HtmlString` but I couldn't implement that to my code.

Comment: Don't do everything inline; move your query to a variable, loop over the results and construct the HTML, like `$html = ''; foreach($results as $result){ $html += ... }`, replacing `...` with the URL for each user, then `->line(new HtmlString($html))`

Comment: @TimLewis I just updated the question with my `email.blade.php`. Your approach worked, the lines are clickable right now. But, every line is clickable. How can I seperate clickable lines for lines which shouldn't be clickable. My greeting, information lines are also clickable.

Comment: @lolkesh I've added an (untested) example how you could solve your problem without having to modify a template file. But Tim's comment still stands. My code's not perfect. You would have to refactor it.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the wrong syntax, would be something like `->map(function($student, $index){ return '<a href="' . url("/students/{$student->id}") . '">' . $student->name . '</a>'; })`. But you had the right idea :D

Comment: Oh, I was still using `pluck` for this example. It would obviously be better to use the actual object since the data was already there.

Comment: Big thanks to both of you, thank you for the tips and the solution! I wish good luck to both of you in the life...